# check syntax of ruby/jruby script using jruby -c syntax check (inside ruby code)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, file-io, jruby, eval

I am in a search of some way , using which in ruby code I should be able to create a temp file and then append some ruby code in that, then pass that temp file path to jruby -c to check for any syntax errors.

Currently I am trying the following approach:

```
script_file = File.new("#{Rails.root}/test.rb", "w+") 
            script_file.print(content)
            script_file.close
command = "#{RUBY_PATH} -c #{Rails.root}/test.rb"
            eval(command);
            new_script_file.close
```

When I inspect command var, it is properly showing jruby -c {ruby file path}. But when I execute the above piece of code I am getting the following error:

> Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 41ms
>
> SyntaxError ((eval):1: dhunknown regexp options - dh):

Let me know if any one has any idea on this.

Thanks,
Dean

Answer (score 1):

**eval** evaluates the string as **Ruby code**, not as a command line invocation:
Since your command is not valid Ruby syntax, you get this exception.

If you want to launch a command in Ruby, you can use %x{} or ``:

> output1 = `ls`
>
> output2 = %x{ls}

Both forms will return the output of the launched command as a String, if you want to process it. If you want this output to be directly displayed in the user terminal, you can use system():

> system("ls")

Comment: Yes, I tried the above method also, but it was not giving me output on variable output was coming in the terminal, so i have done the following changes:
    command = "#{RUBY_PATH} -c #{Rails.root}/test.rb"
    test_output = `#{command} 2>&1`
In this way output was coming in test_output variable.

Comment: It is because jruby -c itself prints its diagnostic messages to the error stream STDERR: By default, all the previous form only capture the standard output (STDOUT). If you want to capture the error stream directly, you can use something as IO#popen: `IO.popen(command) { |f| f.stderr.read }`

Comment: The previous code does not work: To achieve this, Popen3 can be used: http://mentalized.net/journal/2010/03/08/5_ways_to_run_commands_from_ruby/